# Sum specific field of relational field in Prisma

Tags: sql, mysql, prisma

I am newer to Prisma and have two MySql tables, recipebook and comments, they are connected by a foreign key relation on the recipeid field in recipebook. How would I go about writing a prisma query that returns all recipes in recipebook with the sum of all the ratings per each recipe from the comments table.

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE recipebook (
 recipeid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(45),
 description VARCHAR(45),
 ingredients JSON,
 cooktime INT,
 instructions MEDIUMTEXT,
 imgurl VARCHAR(200),
 imgkey VARCHAR(200),
 author VARCHAR(45),
 userid INT,
 CONSTRAINT userid_idx FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES 
 users(userid) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 );

CREATE TABLE comments (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 rating INT,
 comment VARCHAR(280),
 recipeid INT,
 author VARCHAR(45),
 authorid INT,
 CONSTRAINT authorid_idx FOREIGN KEY (authorid) REFERENCES 
 users(userid) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT recipeid_fk FOREIGN KEY (recipeid) REFERENCES 
 recipebook(recipeid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 );
```

I am able to select the comments with the specific recipe but not sure where to go next to sum the specific rating field for each recipebook entry.

```
const recipes = await prisma.recipebook.findMany({
    include: {
        comments: {
          select: {
            rating: true,
          },
        },
      },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use the `select` and `aggregate` features in Prisma. Try this:

1. First, you'll want to select all the fields from the `recipebook` table.
2. Then, for the `comments` relation, you'll want to aggregate the `rating` field to get its sum.

Here's a modified Prisma query:

```js
const recipes = await prisma.recipebook.findMany({
  select: {
    recipeid: true,
    name: true,
    description: true,
    ingredients: true,
    cooktime: true,
    instructions: true,
    imgurl: true,
    imgkey: true,
    author: true,
    userid: true,
    comments: {
      select: {
        _count: true,
        _sum: {
          rating: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

// Now, each recipe in the `recipes` array will have a `comments` field with the total count of comments and the sum of ratings.
```

- `_count` will give you the total number of comments for each recipe.
- `_sum` will give you the sum of ratings for each recipe.

You can then access the sum of ratings for each recipe using `recipe.comments._sum.rating` and the count of comments using `recipe.comments._count`.

Comment: recipe.comments._sum.rating returns an error for the unknown field of _sum.

Comment: May need to take a two-step approach depending on how large the recipe library is. Can you provide more information on how big the library is?

Comment: very small now, like less than 20 elements.